# Stopping animate, increasing circle radius with KineticJS on mousedown

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

this is my first question here so if there is any additional information you require please let me know.

So my goal is to be able to click on the moving circle and have its movement stopped and while the mouse button is down have its radius increased steadily (like an expanding balloon). Currently I have it so the radius expands by 1 when the mouse is down and then it goes bonkers once I mouse up (I would like it to keep moving with its new radius on mouse up).

Here is my code:

HTML

```
  <html>
    <head>  
    <meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">      
        <div id="stage"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    margin: 10% auto;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
}
#stage{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript

```
var circlevx = 5;
var circlevy = 5;
var runAnimation = true;
/*******************************
setting up the stage/layers
********************************/
window.onload = function(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container : 'stage',
        width : 900,
        height : 600
    });
    var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    /**********************************
        creating the circle object
    *************************************/
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x : stage.getWidth() / 2,
        y : stage.getHeight() / 2,
        radius : 50,
        fill : 'grey',
        stroke : 'black',
        strokeWidth : 1
    });


    /*************************************
        add the circle to the stage
    **************************************/
    //bindingBox.add(circle);
    shapesLayer.add(circle);
    stage.add(shapesLayer);

    var date = new Date();
    var time = date.getTime();
    animate(time, circle, runAnimation);
}

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();   


function animate(lastTime, circle, runAnimation){   
    if(runAnimation) {      
        var stage = circle.getStage();
        var shapesLayer = circle.getLayer();
        var date = new Date();
        var time = date.getTime();
        var timeDiff = time - lastTime;

        // update
        updateCircle(timeDiff, circle);

        // draw
        shapesLayer.draw();

        // request new frame
        requestAnimFrame(function(){
            animate(time, circle, runAnimation);
        });
    }
}

function updateCircle(timeDiff, circle){
    var stage = circle.getStage().attrs;
    var circleX = circle.attrs.x;
    var circleY = circle.attrs.y;
    var circleRadius = circle.attrs.radius;
    var newRadius = circleRadius + 2;
    circleX += circlevx; 
    circleY += circlevy;
    //console.log(stage);

    //throw 'aarg';
    // ceiling condition
    if (circleY < circleRadius) {
        circleY = circleRadius;
        circlevy *= -1;
    }

    // floor condition
    if (circleY > (stage.height - circleRadius)) {
        //console.log('bottom');
        circleY = stage.height - circleRadius;
        circlevy *= -1;
    }

    // right wall condition
    if (circleX > (stage.width - circleRadius)) {
        circleX = stage.width - circleRadius;
        circlevx *= -1;
    }

    // left wall condition
    if (circleX < (circleRadius)) {
        circleX = circleRadius;
        circlevx *= -1;
    }

    circle.setPosition(circleX, circleY);
    //
    circle.on('mousedown', function(){
        runAnimation = false;
        circle.setRadius(newRadius);
    });
    circle.on('mouseup', function(){
        runAnimation = true;
        if(runAnimation) {
            var date = new Date();
            var time = date.getTime();
            animate(time, circle, runAnimation);
        }       
        console.log('mouseout');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use a Kinetic Tween to control the expansion of you "balloon"**

First, declare these useful additional properties on the Kinetic balloon object:

```
    balloon.X=150;
    balloon.Y=150;
    balloon.VX=0.50;
    balloon.VY=0.50;
    balloon.RAF;
    balloon.tw;
```

On balloon `mousedown` cancel the movement animation and start the tween to expand the balloon:

You can continue expanding the balloon if you again press the mouse down.

```
    balloon.on("mousedown",function(){
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.RAF);
        this.tw=new Kinetic.Tween({
            node:this,
            duration:3,
            radius:100
        });
        this.tw.play();
    });
```

Then on `mouseup`, pause the inflation tween and restart the move animation:

The balloon will retain its expanded size.

Note: if you have the mouse down and move off the balloon to release the mouse,  this `mouseup` will not be called and the balloon will continue to expand, even though the mouse is up.

```
    balloon.on("mouseup",function(){
        this.tw.pause();
        this.move();
    });
```

Here is the RAF animation function added to the balloon object to do balloon movement:

```
    balloon.move=function(){

        // calc new balloon position
        this.X+=this.VX;
        this.Y+=this.VY;

        // reverse if colliding
        var r=this.getRadius();
        if(this.X<r){ this.VX*=-1; this.X=r; }
        if(this.X>stageWidth-r){ this.VX*=-1; this.X=stageWidth-r; }
        if(this.Y<r){ this.VY*=-1; this.Y=r; }
        if(this.Y>stageHeight-r){ this.VY*=-1; this.Y=stageHeight-r; }

        // set the new balloon position
        this.setPosition(this.X,this.Y);
        layer.draw();

        // request a new animation loop
        var b=this;
        this.RAF=requestAnimationFrame(function(){ b.move();});
    }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/D7Ndc/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stageWidth=300;
    var stageHeight=300;

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: stageWidth,
        height: stageHeight
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // create a balloon object
    var balloon = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        radius: 20,
        fill: 'skyblue',
        stroke: 'lightgray',
        strokeWidth: 3,
    });
    balloon.X=150;
    balloon.Y=150;
    balloon.VX=0.50;
    balloon.VY=0.50;
    balloon.RAF;
    balloon.move=function(){

        // calc new balloon position
        this.X+=this.VX;
        this.Y+=this.VY;

        // reverse if colliding
        var r=this.getRadius();
        if(this.X<r){ this.VX*=-1; this.X=r; }
        if(this.X>stageWidth-r){ this.VX*=-1; this.X=stageWidth-r; }
        if(this.Y<r){ this.VY*=-1; this.Y=r; }
        if(this.Y>stageHeight-r){ this.VY*=-1; this.Y=stageHeight-r; }

        // set the new balloon position
        this.setPosition(this.X,this.Y);
        layer.draw();

        // request a new animation loop
        var b=this;
        this.RAF=requestAnimationFrame(function(){ b.move();});
    }
    balloon.tw;
    balloon.on("mousedown",function(){
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.RAF);
        this.tw=new Kinetic.Tween({
            node:this,
            duration:3,
            radius:100
        });
        this.tw.play();
    });
    balloon.on("mouseup",function(){
        this.tw.pause();
        this.move();
    });

    layer.add(balloon);

    balloon.move();

    layer.draw();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works well, thanks! Do you have any idea on how to get the circle to stop moving until the mouse up has been triggered? Currently I click on the circle, and it expands to 100 without stopping.

Comment: I have added to my answer to include an animation that move the balloon.  The animation is stopped while the mouse is down on the balloon.

Comment: Thanks very much, this definitely gives me more to work with!